# Newsletter ad is still using old logo

Tags: bug, design

The newsletter ad for this site appears to be still using the old logo:

[image: Has the old 'chip' logo with an email symbol laid on top of it]

Now that I look at it, the newsletter itself is also using the old design.

Comment: The letterheads which were printed back in the day haven't run out yet.

Comment: The newsletter itself still uses the old design, as per http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/design-update-is-now-live/5461#5461

Comment: Does anybody read the newsletter?

Comment: @MattYoung I skim the newsletter when I don't have time to visit the site regularly.